# iPhone 6, charged overnight and now stuck in bootloop

Tags: iphone, reboot

I left my phone charging overnight, and in the morning I woke up and the phone was stuck in bootloop.
The Apple logo came on, then the screen turned white, sometimes with 1 black horizontal line or sometimes a pixel (greenish).

Answer (score 1):

While the screen is white I would try [force restarting](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/How+to+Force+Restart+an+iPhone+6/44408).

If that doesn't work, and you have a computer and some time, I would force it into [DFU mode](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/DFU_Mode) and restore it with iTunes.

HOWEVER, do not use DFU mode if you do not have a backup of the phone. In that case, I would take it to the nearest Apple Store and ask how they would suggest recovering your data.